# How can I add colons and remove "p/pp" from in-text citations with BibLaTeX?

Tags: latex, biblatex

I'm referencing Harvard style in a paper, and I'd like to slightly edit the way in-text citations come out. I am using Biblatex, and I have used some specifications to make in-text citations and bibliography compliant with Harvard referencing, so that's all well and good.

In-text citations, however, don't look quite the way I want them. Year and page numbers are separated by comma, but I'd like a colon, and "p/pp" are inserted before page numbers. I'd rather remove that.

Currently, my pre-amb looks like the following:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{dcolumn}  
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{geometry} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\setlength{\headsep}{1.2cm} 
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt} 
\pagestyle{fancy} 


\lhead{Header}   
\chead{Headrer}  
\rhead{Header}   


\usepackage{setspace} 
\doublespacing 

\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{color}    
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{hanging}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes} 
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref} 


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}


\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}


\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, giveninits=true, uniquename=init, backend=biber, maxbibnames=99, innamebeforetitle = true,]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first} 
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}  

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}


\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
    \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
\nocite{*}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:in:editor}[1]{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test \ifuseeditor
        and
        not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
    }
    {\ifboolexpr{togl {bbx:innameidem} and test {\bbx@ineditoridem}}
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}
        {\printnames[ineditor][1-42]{editor}}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{#1}%
        \clearname{editor}}
    {}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\chap[1]{
    \chapter*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
    \markboth{#1}{#1}}


\newcommand\secTOC[1]{
    \section*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
    \markboth{#1}{#1}}


\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\noindent Example sentence \parencite[20-22]{Andreadisetal}. Another sentence \parencite[30-31]{Bruns&Highfield}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The references are:

```
@InCollection{Andreadisetal,
  author    = {Andreadis, I. and Cremonesi, C. and Kartsounidou, E. and Kasprowicz, D. and Hess, A.},
  title     = {Attitudinal and Behavioral Responses to Populist Communication: The Impact of Populist Message Elements on Populist Attitudes and Voting Intentions},
  booktitle = {Communicating populism: comparing actor perceptions, media coverage, and effects on citizens in Europe},
  year      = {2019},
  publisher = {Routledge},
  location  = {New York},
  editor   = {Reinemann, C. and Stanyer, J. and Aalberg, T. and Esser, F. and De Vreese, C.H.},
}

@InCollection{Bruns&Highfield,
  author    = {Bruns, A. and Highfield, T.},
  title     = {Is Habermas on Twitter? Social Media and the Public Sphere},
  booktitle = {The Routledge Companion to Social Media and Politics},
  year      = {2016},
  editor    = {Bruns, A. and Enli, G. and Skogerbø, E. and Larsson, A.O. and Christensen, C.},
  publisher = {Routledge},
  location  = {New York},
}
```

When I run it, the output looks like this:

[image]

But I'd like it to be: (Andreadis et al., 2019: 20-22) and Bruns and Highfield, 2016: 30-31) with colons instead of commas between year and pages, and to forego the p/pp altogether.

What options can I use to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove `pp.` and `p.` with

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  page             = {},
  pages            = {},
}
```

and replace the comman with a colon:

```
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon}
```

---

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{dcolumn}  
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{geometry} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\setlength{\headsep}{1.2cm} 
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt} 
\pagestyle{fancy} 


\lhead{Header}   
\chead{Headrer}  
\rhead{Header}   


\usepackage{setspace} 
\doublespacing 

\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{color}    
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{hanging}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes} 
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref} 


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}


%\usepackage{fontspec} 
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}


\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, giveninits=true, uniquename=init, backend=biber, maxbibnames=99, innamebeforetitle = true,]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first} 
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}  

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}


\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
    \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
\nocite{*}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:in:editor}[1]{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test \ifuseeditor
        and
        not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
    }
    {\ifboolexpr{togl {bbx:innameidem} and test {\bbx@ineditoridem}}
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}
        {\printnames[ineditor][1-42]{editor}}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{#1}%
        \clearname{editor}}
    {}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\chap[1]{
    \chapter*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
    \markboth{#1}{#1}}


\newcommand\secTOC[1]{
    \section*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
    \markboth{#1}{#1}}


\raggedbottom

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@InCollection{Andreadisetal,
  author    = {Andreadis, I. and Cremonesi, C. and Kartsounidou, E. and Kasprowicz, D. and Hess, A.},
  title     = {Attitudinal and Behavioral Responses to Populist Communication: The Impact of Populist Message Elements on Populist Attitudes and Voting Intentions},
  booktitle = {Communicating populism: comparing actor perceptions, media coverage, and effects on citizens in Europe},
  year      = {2019},
  publisher = {Routledge},
  location  = {New York},
  editor   = {Reinemann, C. and Stanyer, J. and Aalberg, T. and Esser, F. and De Vreese, C.H.},
}

@InCollection{Bruns&Highfield,
  author    = {Bruns, A. and Highfield, T.},
  title     = {Is Habermas on Twitter? Social Media and the Public Sphere},
  booktitle = {The Routledge Companion to Social Media and Politics},
  year      = {2016},
  editor    = {Bruns, A. and Enli, G. and Skogerbø, E. and Larsson, A.O. and Christensen, C.},
  publisher = {Routledge},
  location  = {New York},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  page             = {},
  pages            = {},
} 
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon}


\begin{document}

\noindent Example sentence \parencite[20-22]{Andreadisetal}. Another sentence \parencite[30-31]{Bruns&Highfield}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]